# When using npm install for local package, all files are included

Tags: node.js, npm

I am setting up my local module to be installed via `npm install --save ../path/to/my/project`.

When running the npm install, the `node_modules/my_project` directory gets populated with all source files - not just the `dist/` folder as configured in `package.json`. I'm not sure why.

Here's my setup:

## Test Project (main project)

Files:

```
index.js
package.json
dist/
    index.js
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "a test",
    "main": "dist/index.js",
    "files": [
        "dist"
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "keywords": [
        "test"
    ],
    "author": "Me",
    "license": "MIT"
}
```

-

### Test Project2 (to import main project as a dependency)

package.json

```
{
    "name": "test2",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "test2",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author": "Me",
    "license": "MIT",
    "dependencies": {
        "test": "file:../test"
    }
}
```

Once I run `npm install`, my `node_modules/` directory looks like this:

```
test/
    index.js
    package.json
    dist/
        index.js
```

Is there something I'm overlooking? I'm under the assumption that the `files: []` field is used to specify which files are included when the package is installed.

Additionally, I've tried running `npm cache clean -f` and `npm cache verify`, neither of which solve my issue.

Comment: do you have a .npmignore  ?

Comment: I did, but it did nothing. All files present. I believe .npmignore is for publish?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this only occurs when attempting to install a local module. To test, I made a test repo on github and installed from there, only the `dist/` file was included. Not sure why.